# What's the idiomatic way in R to return a vector of function values when the function takes no input?

Tags: r

Suppose I write a function that takes no input but returns random variable e.g.,

```
example.f <- function() runif(1, 0, 1)
```

If I want to get a vector of length 100 of results returned from this function, I can't do this:

```
rep(example.f(), 100)
```

as it just repeats the first returned value. I could do it like this, with an anonymous function:

```
sapply(1:100, function(x) example.f())
```

but this strikes me as a bit inelegant. Is there another way?

Comment: There is bug in you example with rep. You should put parenthesis after function exmaple.f.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use replicate:

```
replicate(100, example.f())
```

Comment: truly functional programmers use plyr's `r_ply` instead